# Change detection break without errors since Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

There is one specific property in my service that breaks all my view bindings/change detections when i bind it somewhere in my view. This happened since i updated from Angular 2.x to 4.0.2

---

### About the environment

In order to figure this out i created a simple BindingTestComponent. The template looks like this:

```
<button (click)="toggleName()">Toggle Name</button>
<div>Test: {{name}}!</div>
```

The BindingTestComponent typescript isn’t much more than this:

```
name : string = 'Tom';
toggleName() {
    this.name = this.name === 'Tom' ? 'Jerry' : 'Tom';
}
```

Now i can click on the button and the name toggles between Tom and Jerry.

The issue appears when i use `workTime.duration` somewhere else in the same view that also includes BindingTestComponent. Like:

```
<div>{{workTime.duration}}</div>
<binding-test></binding-test>
```

When i click on the »Toggle Name« button nothing happens. The browser console sadly shows no error.

Interestingly i can fix the BindingTextComponent behavior by using the [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html) like so:

```
toggleName() {
    this.name = this.name === 'Tom' ? 'Jerry' : 'Tom';
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

### About the service property

It returns an duration like so:

```
get duration() {
  let currentTime = new Date();
  let startedWork = new Date(1492074996355);
  return currentTime - startedWork;
}
```

---

I can guess that its problematic that the property is never stable. It has a different value every time you request it. But..

**How can i solve this?**

and

**Shouldn’t this give me an error in the browser console?**

Comment: I think it works as expected. There was a bug before v4.https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15464#issuecomment-292978054

Comment: the comment said »...you should expect this kind of error...« but i dont get an error. And no changes get detected anymore. Not in BindingTestComponent and not in any other Component that is included in my view.

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: @yurzui i tried and it gives me an error. Sadly, i can’t see any difference between my setup and the plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/QKoe9qiCIYg4064fpCVd?p=preview Thanks anyway.